# jQuery.clone() IE problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, clone

I'm have some that uses jQuery.clone() to get the html of a page and then add it to a pre tag. It works correctly in Firefox and Chrome, but nothing happens in IE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script>
$(function(){

  $('button').click(function(){
    var $clone = $('html').clone();
    $('#output').text($clone.html());
  });

});
</script>
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <button>run test</button>
  <pre id="output"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any know bug with IE that prevents this, or am I doing something wrong?

*(I need to clone it because I'm doing some changes to it before outputting it)*

Comment: You're adding the equivalent of an entire document (including a `<head>`, `<body>`) *back into* the current document and wondering why it doesn't work? I'm surprised it works at all, in any browser.

Comment: Did you try just to use contents()?  http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: @Roatin Marth - He's using `.text()` and placing it into a `pre` container. Obviously he intends to display the markup of the page in `#output`.

Comment: @patrick: ah sorry, missed that thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just show the page text in the page, try this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('#output').empty().html(('<html>\n  ' + $('html').html() + '\n</html>')
     .replace(/&/gm, '&amp;')
     .replace(/</gm, '&lt;')
     .replace(/>/gm, '&gt;')
     .replace(/\r/gm, '')
     .replace(/\n/gm, '<br>')
   );
});
```

That works for me in Chrome, Firefox, and IE8.

Comment: thanks :) but i also need to remove some elements from the original html, how can I do that with you method?

Comment: Well, you could do your `clone()` operation, mess with it however you want, and then work with the `.html()` value of the result.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to work in IE, Firefox & Safari. I'm calling the javascript DOM API `cloneNode()` method instead of jQuery's `clone()`. Don't know why it works. You should probably do some more browser testing.

```
var $scripts = $('script');            // Cache all scripts in the document

var html = $('html').get(0).cloneNode(true);  // Clone HTML using DOM API

var $html = $(html);                     // Make jQuery object from cloned HTML

$('script', $html).each(function(i) {       // Loop through scripts in $html
    this.text = $scripts.get(i).innerHTML;  //  replacing content with that
});                                         //  from the cached $scripts

$('#output').empty().text($html.html());    // Append to #output
```

Comment: almost, but it removes embedded scripts. like if i have <script> var test = true; </script>. only the <script></script> tags are left. any ideas?

Comment: OK, I think I've got it. Since IE kindly leaves us the empty `script` tags, all we need to do is cache those first, clone our `html`, then updated the empty `script` tags with the content of the cached ones. Seems to work. I updated my answer. Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed one big difference in what clone does in IE and others. In IE, it appears to clone everything, including script tags. Therefore if you have code inside the script tag that instantiates code, it will be instantiated again. In the case of this question it is probably encountering an infinite loop since it will continually call the code to clone itself.