# JQuery IE7 clone returns '0' is null or not an object

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery-1.6 with jquery-validation-1.9.0, jquery.form.2.36, jquery-ui-1.8.2 plugins.

I copy of the following block of code, which can contain one to many radio buttons which are grouped by element name 'corsdt'

```
 <div class="container-wrapper">
....
    <div class="rght-container">
       <input type="radio" name="corsdt" id="rad_corsdt_1" class="radio ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="course_title=Fundamentals%20for%20New%20Managers&amp;course_code=341.564&amp;mercref=341.564-12-HI-03" />
    </div>
 </div>
```

and append it to a form, using jquery

```
var $clone = $('.container-wrapper').clone();

    var crsrads = $clone.find("input:radio[name=corsdt]");

var no_of_rad = crsrads.length + 1; //find total no. of orig radio inputs, incr ids to avoid duplicate ids
    crsrads.each(function(index){
        var i = index + no_of_rad;
        $(this).attr({id: 'rad_corsdt_' + i, name: 'corsdt1'});
    });

 $('#dialog-dtwrapper').append($clone);
```

This appends to the target div tag within a form, as expected

```
<div id="dialog-dtwrapper">
      <div class="container-wrapper">
       ....
         <div class="rght-container"><input id="rad_corsdt_2" class="radio ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ez-hide valid" type="radio" value="course_title=Fundamentals%20for%20New%20Managers&amp;course_code=341.564&amp;mercref=341.564-12-HI-03" name="corsdt1">
      ...      
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However when I try to validate the form, using the validation plugin, I get an, '0' is null or not an object, error in IE7.

```
var aform = $("#formName").validate({
....
rules: {
 ....
  corsdt1 : "required",
 ....
},
messages: { 
....
 corsdt1 : "please select a course date",

},
submitHandler: function(form) {....
```

I assume that this is related to the clone method which in some instances causes a bug in IE7.Is there a work around for this?

As this works fine in Firefox, IE8 & Chrome.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var html = $('.container-wrapper').get(0).cloneNode(true);  // Clone HTML using DOM API
var $clone = $(html);
```

I had this problem before and it was solved like this.

Reference link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2874893/17447

Comment: @naween, thanks for this, but the clone method is working as I can see the fragment was correctly cloned in IE developer (IE7).

It's the validation, that isn't working, if I comment out the 'corsdt1' rule, it all works fine.

Not sure why it returns a 'null object' when it is clearly present in the dom??

Answer (score 0):

```
var crsrads = $clone.find("input:radio[name=corsdt]");
```

should be

```
var crsrads = $clone.find('input:radio[name="corsdt"]');
```